# iOS - center content of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, custom-controls

I am trying to create UIView with image and number. I want to center them. For now I have this code:

```
    CGRect likesRect = CGRectMake(0,152, screenWidth / 2, 30);
    MARoundedRect *likesRoundedRect = [[MARoundedRect alloc] initWithFrame:likesRect];

    UIView *likesView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    likesView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth / 4, 20);

    UIImageView *likeImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    likeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite.png"];

    UILabel *likesLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, screenWidth / 2, 20)];
    [likesLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [likesLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
    [likesLabel setText:[actualPlace.Favorites stringValue]];

    [likesView addSubview:likeImage];
    [likesView addSubview:likesLabel];
    [likesRoundedRect addSubview:likesView];
    [viewController.view addSubview:likesRoundedRect];
```

For now it's working good but I am setting width of likesView to exact value and I guess this goes bad when I don't have number with one or two letters but more. How can I fix this? How to center content of UIView if there are two or more components with side by side? Or how can I set UIView to dynamically change width by content? Thanks

Comment: Are you able to use auto-layout?

Comment: I guess so, it must just be in code (programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

I am not writing full code but you try with following code,

```
CGRect likesRect = CGRectMake(0,152, screenWidth / 2, 30);
MARoundedRect *likesRoundedRect = [[MARoundedRect alloc] initWithFrame:likesRect];

CGSize likeViewSize = CGSizeMake(50,30);
UIView *likesView = [[UIView alloc] init];
likesView.frame = CGRectMake(likesRoundedRect.frame.size.width/2 - likeViewSize.width/2,likesRoundedRect.frame.size.height/2 - likeViewSize.height/2,likeViewSize.width,likeViewSize.height);
```

I have centered the `likesView` on its parentview. you have to do same thing for label and imageview if you want to center them on their parentview (`likesView`)

Answer (score 0):

UIView and  its subclasses has a property called center :

```
 CGPoint center1 = CGPointmake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2,  
         self.view.bounds.size,height/2) ; 

  subview.center = center1;
```

The following discussion is from the Apple documentation on UIView:

@property(nonatomic) CGPoint center
Discussion
The center is specified within the coordinate system of its superview and is measured in points. Setting this property changes the values of the frame properties accordingly.

Changing the frame rectangle automatically redisplays the receiver without invoking the drawRect: method. If you want the drawRect: method invoked when the frame rectangle changes, set the contentMode property to UIViewContentModeRedraw.

Changes to this property can be animated. Use the beginAnimations:context: class method to begin and the commitAnimations class method to end an animation block.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
See Also
  @property frame
  @property bounds
  @property transform
Related Sample Code
AVLoupe
Handling Touches Using Responder Methods and Gesture Recognizers
iAdInterstitialSuite
iAdSuite
RosyWriter
Declared In
UIView.h